# What is "this stage's default asynchronous execution facility"? (Java CompletionStage/CompletableFuture)

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, completion-stage

In Oracle Java documentation for [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) and [ComletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) all `*Async` methods  without an explicit Executor argument refer to some *stage's default asynchronous execution facility*

> executes the given action using this stage's default asynchronous execution facility

But what is this "execution facility" is not explicitly defined! Does this mean some default executor/tread pool?

At least `ComletableFuture` doc mentions:

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`

So, does this mean that `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` is a "default asynchronous execution facility"?

What else, besides a thread pool and an `Executor` could be a "default asynchronous execution facility"?

Comment: yes, but even `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` is not defined within the spec or documentation, so it's *an implementation detail*

Comment: You mean for `Completion*Stage*`, but for `Completable*Future*` common ForkJoinPool i explicitly defined and documented, isn't it?

Comment: right, to be honest I entirely missed `CompletableFuture` documentation, still had my head in streams... my bad and thank you